# Mapping does not retrieve any value

Tags: java, jpa

I have got a Client object that has mapping to Residential and Postal addresses based on DescripterCustomizer implementation (in AddressFilter). However, when I retrieve the client by id it does not populate the addresses. Anyone can help? My classes look as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cli_clients")
@Customizer(AddressFilter.class)
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="client_type", discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Client implements Serializable {
@EmbeddedId
protected ClientPK id;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_roid", referencedColumnName = "c_roid")
private Address currentResidentialAddress;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="client", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_roid", referencedColumnName = "c_roid")
private Address currentPostalAddress;
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "cli_addresses")
public class Address implements Serializable{
@EmbeddedId
private AddressPK id;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "c_roid", referencedColumnName = "c_roid")
private Client client;
...
}

public class AddressFilter implements DescriptorCustomizer{

@Override
public void customize(ClassDescriptor descriptor) throws Exception {
    defineCurrentResidentialAddressCriteria(descriptor);
    defineCurrentPostalAddressCriteria(descriptor);
}

private void defineCurrentResidentialAddressCriteria(ClassDescriptor descriptor){
    OneToOneMapping mapping = (OneToOneMapping) descriptor.getMappingForAttributeName("currentResidentialAddress");
    if (mapping == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find mapping for address.currentResidentialAddress");
    }

    Expression baseExp = mapping.buildSelectionCriteria();
    ExpressionBuilder eb = baseExp.getBuilder();
    Expression addressTypeExpression = eb.get("addressType.code").equal(AddressType.RESIDENTIAL);
    Expression endDateExpression = eb.get("toDateTime").greaterThan(eb.currentDate()).or(eb.get("toDateTime").isNull());

mapping.setSelectionCriteria(baseExp.and(addressTypeExpression).and(endDateExpression));
}

private void defineCurrentPostalAddressCriteria(ClassDescriptor descriptor){
    OneToOneMapping mapping = (OneToOneMapping) descriptor.getMappingForAttributeName("currentPostalAddress");
    if (mapping == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find mapping for address.currentPostalAddress");
    }

    Expression baseExp = mapping.buildSelectionCriteria();
    ExpressionBuilder eb = baseExp.getBuilder();
    Expression addressTypeExpression = eb.get("addressType.code").equal(AddressType.POSTAL);
    Expression endDateExpression = eb.get("toDateTime").greaterThan(eb.currentDate()).or(eb.get("toDateTime").isNull());

    mapping.setSelectionCriteria(baseExp.and(addressTypeExpression).and(endDateExpression));
}
}
```

Comment: The mappings are confusing, as both are mappedby the client relationship back, and both state they use the c_roid field to join on.  This conflicts, as either the other side defines the joincolumn or this side should, not both, and you should get exceptions because both are mapping to the same foreign key, and one side must reference the other side's primary key - c_roid doesn't seem to be set anywhere and both sides use an embeddedid implying multiple fields are used as the id.  Turn on logging to see the SQL that is generated to see if your custom mapping criteria is used

Comment: The SQL does not have any of the custom criteria. So, I debugged into the Filter. It only goes in when I try inserting a Client entity. Any client retrieval does not get kicked off the custom filter for the Address. In the database, only the Address has the foreign key to the Client. I tried to put the postal and residential addresses on Client for convenience sake so I do not have to retrieve them separately.